# WinUI3 : Understanding WinUI3 desktop app

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, winui-3

As we can create a WinUI3 app in both the desktop app(win32 app) and the UWP app. What exactly does it mean to create a WinUI3 in a desktop app? As I understand, this app will follow the Win32 App model, that is, the app will not run on sandbox and the app will not have [activation and lifecycle management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) like UWP apps. Is this right?

In this case, How can we use Win32 APIs in this project, and can we follow the event loop like the [WNDPROC callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-wndproc) instead of Application::Start()?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you have posted the same case on the Q&A forum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1095079/winui3-understanding-winui3-desktop-app.html

You could refer to the answer provided by Castorix 31. To prevent the link from expiring, I will post the answer to Castorix 31:

> Application::Start replaces the main message loop.
> As it is a Win32 app, you can have access to the main window WndProc with
> SetWindowSubclass.

Comment: Yea had some more queries which I was discussing in the comments, thought of updating it here when I got a full clarity